# How to transform an Android Task to a Kotlin Deferred?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

Firebase anonymous sign in returns a [task](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) (which is basically [Google promise implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)):

```
val task:Task<AuthResult> = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously()
```

How it would be possible create a `signInAnonymous` wrapper where:

- It is a `suspend` function, waiting for the `task` completion

  - `suspend fun signInAnonymous(): Unit`
- It returns a `Deferred` object, delivering the result asynchronously

  - `fun signInAnonymous() : Deferred`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The package [`kotlinx.coroutines.tasks`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/src/Tasks.kt#L80) now includes the follwing utility functions:

```
public suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): T { ... }
```

From the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html):

> Awaits for completion of the task without blocking a thread.
>   This suspending function is cancellable.
>   If the [Job](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/index.html) of the current coroutine is cancelled or completed while this suspending function is waiting, this function stops waiting for the completion stage and immediately resumes with [CancellationException](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-cancellation-exception.html).

```
public fun <T> Task<T>.asDeferred(): Deferred<T> { ... }
```

From the [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/as-deferred.html):

> Converts this task to an instance of [Deferred](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/index.html).
>   If task is cancelled then resulting deferred will be cancelled as well.

---

So you can just do:

```
suspend fun signInAnonymouslyAwait(): AuthResult {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously().await()
}
```

or:

```
fun signInAnonymouslyDeferred(): Deferred<AuthResult> {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously().asDeferred()
}
```

Comment: For those looking for the maven repository, it's  [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services)

Comment: Blog explanation here https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-with-firebase-6f8577a3e00f

Answer (score 16):

Based on [this GitHub library](https://github.com/lucasvalenteds/firebase-admin-coroutines/blob/main/firebase-tasks/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/firebase/tasks/TaskApi.kt), here's a way to transform a `Task` into a suspending function in the ["usual" way](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#suspending-functions) to adapt callback based async calls to coroutines:

```
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await(): T = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            continuation.resume(task.result)
        } else {
            continuation.resumeWithException(task.exception ?: RuntimeException("Unknown task exception"))
        }
    }
}
```

You can also wrap it in a `Deferred` of course, `CompletableDeferred` comes in handy here:

```
fun <T> Task<T>.asDeferred(): Deferred<T> {
    val deferred = CompletableDeferred<T>()

    deferred.invokeOnCompletion {
        if (deferred.isCancelled) {
            // optional, handle coroutine cancellation however you'd like here
        }
    }

    this.addOnSuccessListener { result -> deferred.complete(result) }
    this.addOnFailureListener { exception -> deferred.completeExceptionally(exception) }

    return deferred
}
```

Comment: how to return the value from this function? @zsmb13

both of the function needs to be called inside async.

e.g:

```val tokenFirebase: String = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.asDeferred().await().token```

and ```val tokenFirebase: String = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.await().token```

// await() show a warning, instead: suspend function 'await' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Comment: Yes, both the `await` on `Deferred` and the `await` presented in my answer needs to be called inside a coroutine, as they are suspending functions. I'm not really sure what you're asking though. If you're asking how to start a coroutine, you should see the [coroutine guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md).

Comment: In my case, I want to get the token from firebase, but how to return value from async coroutines.

I've tried this:

```val newToken: String by lazy {
    val token = with(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId) {
        /*GlobalScope.async { asDeferred().await() }*/ // for what? we await() this?
        if (asDeferred().isCompleted && result != null && isSuccessful) result?.token ?: ""
        else ""
    }

    token
}
```

@zsmb13

but the blank or empty string still returned, instead, or did I use the wrong ways? thanks

Answer (score 6):

Add this to gradle

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.4.3'
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
suspend fun login(email: String, pass: String) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).await()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To transform it into a coroutine-ready function, I would use the `Tasks.await()` function from the Tasks API:

```
suspend fun FirebaseAuth.signInAnonymouslyAwait(): AuthResult {
    return Tasks.await(this.signInAnonymously())
}
```

As for Deferred, i'd stick with zsmb13's answer