# How to perform task using Coroutines android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

This is my repository class:

```
class UserRepository(private val appAuth: FirebaseAuth) {

    fun userLogin(email: String,password: String) : Task<AuthResult>{
       return appAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    }
}
```

I want to perform `Task<AuthResult>` using coroutine 
how can I?

Comment: Please explain `perform task`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58678891/4847906. You should be able to just call `await()` on `appAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)`. Also remember to mark your `userLogin()` method as `suspend`.

Comment: cannot find await()

Comment: I see that you need to add another module from `kotlinx` https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services